# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer las filas de una tabla y ponerlas en formato html para enviar como cuerpo de un correo?

Tags: html, stored-procedure, sql-server-2008

Tengo un procedimiento que captura los errores y los almacena en una tabla temporal, luego al final esa tabla temporal la envío en `stored procedure` y la recorro para darle un formato `html` a cada fila para luego agregarlo como cuerpo de un email, de la forma que lo tengo cuando tengo mas de 1000 registros demora demasiado, hay alguna forma mas eficiente de hacerlo, dejo el código del `stored procedure`:

```
declare @tablaErrores varchar(max) = ''
    select @tablaErrores = @tablaErrores +'<tr><td>'+idregistro+'</td><td>'+proceso +'</td><td>'+tablasafectadas +'</td><td>'+llavesafectadas+'</td><td>'+mensajeerror + '</td><td>'+ fechaerror +'</td></tr>' from @datos
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer uso de la sentencia `FOR XML PATH`. Algo más o menos así:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT d.idregistro AS 'td' FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
    (SELECT d.proceso AS 'td' FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
    (SELECT d.tablasafectadas AS 'td' FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
    (SELECT d.llavesafectadas AS 'td' FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
    (SELECT d.mensajeerror AS 'td' FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
    (SELECT d.fechaerror AS 'td' FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
FROM 
    @datos d
FORM XML PATH('tr')
```

Adáptalo a tus necesidades.